# Does this sum converge, and why?

Tags: summation, series-expansion, convergence

Mathematica says the following sum

```
    Sum[(mm Gamma[mm])/
  Gamma[-(1/2) + mm] - (mm^(3/2) - (3 Sqrt[mm])/8 - (7 Sqrt[1/mm])/
    128), {mm, 1, \[Infinity]}]
```

converges and equals

```
1/(5 Sqrt[\[Pi]]) - Zeta[-(3/2)] + 3/8 Zeta[-(1/2)] + 7/128 Zeta[1/2]
```

This seems to make sense, bc the large $mm$ limit

```
Series[(mm Gamma[mm])/Gamma[-(1/2) + mm], {mm, \[Infinity], 1}]
```

gives

```
mm^(3/2) - (3 Sqrt[mm])/8 - (7 Sqrt[1/mm])/128+O(m^{-3/2})
```

which is cancelled by construction in the above convergent sum. But now lets seperately sum each term in the sum to $m$, and look at large $m$:

```
 Series[Sum[(mm Gamma[mm])/
  Gamma[-(1/2) + mm], {mm, 1, m}], {m, \[Infinity], 0}]
```

gives

```
(2 m^(5/2))/5 + m^(3/2)/4 - (11 Sqrt[m])/64 + 1/(5 Sqrt[\[Pi]])+O(m^{-1/2})
```

while

```
 Series[Sum[
   mm^(3/2) - (3 Sqrt[mm])/8 - (7 Sqrt[1/mm])/128, {mm, 1, 
    m}], {m, \[Infinity], 0}] // Simplify
```

gives

```
  (2 m^(5/2))/5 + m^(3/2)/4 - (19 Sqrt[m])/64 + (Zeta[-(3/2)] - 3/8 Zeta[-(1/2)] - 7/128 Zeta[1/2])+O(m^{-1/2})
```

Note that the $m$-independent parts equal the result of the convergent sum above, but the $m^{1/2}$ terms are different. How is this possible? In particular, how could the sum in the beginning be convergent, if each term has a different tail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you develop both terms up to second order the m^(1/2) is no longer there:

```
Expand[FullSimplify[
Normal[Series[Sum[(mm*Gamma[mm])/Gamma[-(1/2) + mm], {mm, 1, m}], 
       {m, Infinity, 2}]]]] - 
Expand[
FullSimplify[
Normal[Series[Sum[mm^(3/2) - 7/(128*Sqrt[mm]) - (3*Sqrt[mm])/8, 
         {mm, 1, m}], {m, Infinity, 2}]]]]
```

Comment: hm, thats weird. How come we needed to expand to second order, in order to get the correct results at a subleading order? this looks like a bug... how do i know if this issue wont show up elsewhere?

Comment: No, it is not so for me: `Series[Sum[(mm Gamma[mm])/Gamma[-(1/2) + mm], {mm, 1, 
     m}], {m, \[Infinity], 2}] - 
  Series[Sum[
    mm^(3/2) - (3 Sqrt[mm])/8 - (7 Sqrt[1/mm])/128, {mm, 1, 
     m}], {m, \[Infinity], 2}] // Simplify` produces $$\left(-\zeta \left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)+\frac{3 \zeta \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{8}+\frac{7 \zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{128}+\frac{1}{5 \sqrt{\pi }}\right)+\frac{9 \sqrt{\frac{1}{m}}}{512}-\frac{1247 \left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^{3/2}}{245760}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^{5/2}\right) $$ in 12.2.

Comment: @user64494 Yes, but the 1/m terms get small for large m

Comment: it seems the asymptotic series of the square root expression  'converges' slower than the gamma term. It works also when you develop only the second part to second order

Comment: @Andreas: You are right.

Answer (score 2):

According to `AsymptoticSum`, the leading term for the series is constant at infinity:

```
AsymptoticSum[
    (mm Gamma[mm])/ Gamma[-(1/2) + mm] - (mm^(3/2) - (3 Sqrt[mm])/8 - (7 Sqrt[1/mm])/128), 
    {mm, 1, n},
    n -> \[Infinity]
]
```

> 1/(5 Sqrt[[Pi]]) - Zeta[-(3/2)] + 3/8 Zeta[-(1/2)] + 7/128 Zeta[1/2]